# How do I cure vampirism?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am at 3 days, I just fed, and I ran down to the Shrine of Talos and pressed it, but it still says I'm a vampire. How do I cure this?

Comment: it's not working I can't find anything that will help I'm a sanguine I feed and then when to the shrine of talos level ten khajiit level 10 because my level 12 was over 3 days I tried to cure at 9:00pm around didn't work please help because I'm not living as a vampire I actually want to play the game

Comment: @Eener9Lilly Saying that you're impatient isn't going to get you more attention or a faster response.

Comment: I'm just saying thags

Comment: this is asking if it's meant to be immediate not how to cure it

Comment: If what is meant to be immediate?

Comment: @Vemonus the cure I fed went to the shrine day 3 vampire nothing happened then I tested it out with a 0 day one same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Ask any bartender about any rumors going around, and they direct the infected person to Falion in Morthal, who studies vampires.
>      Traveling to Morthal while at stage four vampirism can be difficult,
>      since hostile persons will attack the vampire on sight (unless the
>      Dawnguard add-on is installed).
> 2. Once there, he informs the vampire that a ritual can be performed to reverse the curse. A filled black soul gem is required first. The
>      Black Star cannot be substituted for this gem. Falion offers to sell
>      the vampire a Black Soul Gem, if they cannot acquire one through other
>      means.
> 3. Fill the Black Soul Gem by casting Soul Trap on a humanoid target.
> 4. Meet Falion at the stone circle to cure the infection.
> 5. Falion endlessly agrees to cure vampirism, so the quest can be completed multiple times, if infected on more than one occasion.

Or use a console command:
`setstage 0005C625 200`

---

Source: [Elder scrolls wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampirism_(Skyrim)#Curing_vampirism)

Comment: wait how can I use a console command